# What could I use as a metal body for my DIY wind turbine?

Tags: wind

I'm building a Ametek wind turbine, similar to the one in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRn0qn9txS0).

I'm having trouble figuring out what I could use for the metal body, preferably something I could buy from Home Depot or Lowe's. I tried using a sliding closet door bracket, but the base is too small. I need it to be at least 4 inches wide.

Here's what I'm trying to replicate:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk6Ee.png]

Any ideas for what I could use?

Comment: Would a PT 2x6 with a PT 2x4 screwed to the sides work?

Comment: What about 4" sch 40 PVC drain pipe, notched in front for the generator, left whole in back for a through bolt to mount it to the swivel plate.

Comment: That may work, but I'd like to keep the same shape as the picture above with the bottom flat to attach to an iron floor flange seen in this picture: http://www.mdpub.com/Wind_Turbine/images/head_flange2.jpg

Comment: No, I'd like it to be metal, rather than wood since it'll be outside all the time.

Comment: No, and don't build it. Wind turbines are the worst of the "green" technologies; what an oxymoron. You will not recoup your investment, ever, and you'll actually be harming the environment. See "shadow flicker", "low level sound", "vibrations", "kills birds", "pathetic output vs input". Its tantamount to building a fire and rake your money into it. Please watch the documentary "Windfall" before you make another move on this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm already committed to building it for a friend.

Comment: They sell heavy guage metal bracketing (Ls) at HD and Lowes. Just go down that aisle and figure it out.  Love the anti-wind turbine comments!  Who knew a little thing like this would garner such negativity.  Maybe the pirate wouldn't be stranded if he had more wind.   I have 25 oak trees in the front yard and if a turbine will keep the poop off my cars then sign me up.

Comment: The issues the Pirate raises are legitimate concerns in certain situations, and completely non-issues in other situations. It's very reactionary to raise all associated issues without knowing the specific situation. SCALE being an important one for starters.

Comment: Fun project but is this really a Home Improvement question?

Comment: Which piece are you referring to as "the body"? Generator enclosure? The C-bracket it's strapped to in the photo? Other?

Comment: Exactly which part of that photo are you referring to? An arrow would help here.

Comment: Look for a little girl, a small dog, a lion, a scarecrow and a tin woodsman walking on a road with a **very wide** yellow stripe. Nab the tin woodsman and use his body.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a standard 5 gallon plastic bucket, with lid could be cut with a hole for the fan shaft in the bottom and a slot for your mounting pipe on the side. Once mounted, cover the slot w plastic and screw or pop-rivet in place. Wiring will need another hole.
Sun might make the bucket brittle in 5 years, but even with thin metal, you're going to need to do occasional maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The only item I can think of from Lowes or Home Depot would be the metal connectors used for hanging rafters and such. I believe there is one used for setting 4 x 6 inch post base's. It not an exact copy of the piece in the photo, but 2-3 side by side may work. They also sell aluminum gutters which also might work. That base from your photo looks like it's an aluminum channel ,but it might be difficult locating one 4 inches wide. The base also could be (2) separate pieces of aluminum angled stock which have been joined at the bottom (by the floor flange) to form a C channel profile.